# How to order the answers objects by their votes?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Here I want to order the question's answers by their votes. The higher voted answer will be at the top but if it has accepted answer then it will stay at the top like in StackOverflow. How can I do it here?

views

```
class DetailQuestionView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=kwargs['pk'])
        """checking if the current user has voted on the question or not"""
        q_voted = question.question_votes.filter(user=request.user, question=question).exists()
        """getting the list of answers which are voted by the current user"""
        answers = question.answers.all().order_by('votes')  ## how ??
        a_voted_list = [answer for answer in answers if answer.answer_votes.filter(user=request.user, answer=answer)]
        context = {
            'question': question,
            'voted': q_voted,
            'a_voted_list': a_voted_list,
            'answers': answers
        }
```

models

```
class Answer(CommonInfo):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')
    ans = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='user_answers')
    is_accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class AnswerVote(CommonInfo):
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answer_votes')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_votes_ans')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this. it may not work as is. But I think you get the idea.

```
from django.db.models import Count

answers = Answer.objects.filter(question=question) \
                .annotate(answer_vote=Count('answer_vote')) \
                .order_by('-answer_vote')
```

**Edit:**
Ordering first by `is_accepted` then by vote should work.

```
.order_by('-is_accepted', '-answer_vote')
```

Comment: thanks for the answer +1 it worked if the no answer is accepted but if the answer is accepted then I want to keep at first then want to order remaining answers by votes

Comment: may be filter by ```question=question, is_accepted=False``` and then manually prepending accepted answer would be a solution.

Comment: @user12428848 `.order_by('-is_accepted', '-answer_vote')` doesn't work?

Comment: @minglyu i got stuck on this problem. Do have any suggestions ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62753171/how-to-run-my-view-periodically-till-some-end-date