# How to run my view periodically till some end date?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a model for running the scrapy tasks. Now the view returns **scraped** results after some time. There is no any use of two fields `search_frequency` and `scraping_end_date` for now. This fields will be used to run the scrapy view till the scraping_end_date at the given search_frequency value.

For this problem How can I solve? Which approach will be better ? Is django only will be sufficient for this task? Any suggestions will be helpful.

my model looks like this

```
class Task(models.Model):
    task_status = (
        (0, 'running'),
        (1, 'running'),
        (2, 'completed'),
    )

    FREQUENCY = (
        ('1', '1 hrs'),
        ('2', '2 hrs'),
        ('5', '5 hrs'),
        ('10', '10 hrs'),
        ('24', '24 hrs'),
    )
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    scraping_end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=task_status)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    search_frequency = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True, choices=FREQUENCY)
    domain = models.URLField()
```

Comment: You should look at library the entirely handle this king of need, like Celery. Also, execution shouldn't be performed synchronously within the view as it might be cancelled / timeout by the server (Celery handle this case)

Comment: @Blusky can I define the celery  periodic task execution time by the user specified value(search_frequency) ?

Comment: Yes of course, you can define it

Comment: @CharanjitSingh  how can I replace here minutes=5 with the user specified time `@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(minute=5)))` ?

Comment: Instead of creating a `periodic_task` you can prepare next task in previous one, retrieving current user specified time, and preventing task to be executed simultaneously